# Unable to delete untagged images:Error response from daemon: Conflict, 511136 wasn't deleted FATA[0000] Error: failed to remove one or more images

Tags: docker

I am receiving the below error when i try to delete the untagged images.

> ****Error response from daemon: Conflict, 511136 wasn't deleted
>   FATA[0000] Error: failed to remove one or more images****

I have tried all the commands available on the Internet, yet i am unable to delete the images.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Try to add how you have tried to solve it (commands, actions...), so may be we can see some options missing. For example, did you try `docker rmi` with `-f` option? Did you restart Docker daemon? Is there any docker container running or stopped?

Answer (score 0):

First you probably should remove all stopped containers :

`docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

And then remove the images :

`docker rmi $(docker images | grep '^<none>' | awk '{print $3}')`

You can always add the `--force` option, but I'm not sure if everything is cleand correctly then.

With `docker images` the none tags shouldn't be visible anymore.

My source of most of this information : http://jimhoskins.com/2013/07/27/remove-untagged-docker-images.html